# JERSEY: How to retrieve the calling IP or URI using injection annotation?

Tags: java, jersey

I have a REST- Server here using JERSEY. I must log the IP (better the DNS) of the calling client.

Can somebody point a direction which injection annotations to use ?

Searched  "@Context", but could not find anything fitting.

Thanks 
Gerd

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you could add `@Context HttpServletRequest request` as a parameter to your request handler method. And then get a hold of the client IP with `request.getRemoteAddr()`

Comment: RemoteUser comes back null for me, but RemoteHost and RemoteAddr work as planned

Comment: I tried the solution but get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Context to Annotation". How can I solve it?

Comment: @JeffreyLin hard to say from afar :) Maybe you imported a different Context class? make sure you have ```import javax.ws.rs.core.Context```

Answer (score 4):

In case you use Grizzly-Jersey combo, thats the way to do it:

```
@Context
private java.lang.ThreadLocal<org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request> grizzlyRequest;
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 for Grizzly-Jersey combo.
Place in the declaration of the class (extender of ContainerRequestFilter in my case)

```
 @Inject
 private javax.inject.Provider<org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request> request;
```

and later in the code use this.

```
request.get().getRemoteAddr()
```

I dug around and I've found the [resolution in the jersey's jira](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2462). 
Note that they recommend to be used @Inject instead of @Context

I've tried to use

```
  @Context
  private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

which is recommended widely but servletRequest was always null.

*comment servletRequest  was null because I was used GrizzlyHttpServerFactory for creating HttpServer. If you want to have servletRequest  then you need to deploy it with WebappContext. [Take a look here for details](https://github.com/janusdn/jersey2-spring4-grizzly2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/test/Start.java)