# Get IP address of an API sender at receiver end

Tags: java, ip-address

```
@GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/v1//{para1}/{para2}")
    public String registerEvent(@PathParam("para1") String id,
            @PathParam("para2") String ofId) { }
```

This is the used to receive an API from a server in my middleware.
Is it possible to get the sender IP address of the API.

Any information, documentation will be helpful.

Comment: not unless it's sent along with the information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JERSEY: How to retrieve the calling IP or URI using injection annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499596/jersey-how-to-retrieve-the-calling-ip-or-uri-using-injection-annotation)

Comment: There is another SO post about retrieving ip address using incoming HttpServletRequest. Check if that helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910074/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java-httpservletrequest